# iPhone - How to draw something in a view

Tags: iphone, graphics, view, clipping, rect

I'v got this piece of code :

```
CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat colors[] = {
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};
CGGradientRef gradientRef = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgb, colors, NULL, sizeof(colors) / (sizeof(colors[0]) * 4));
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGRect rect = theCell.backgroundView.bounds;                
CGPoint start = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, 0);
CGPoint end = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.size.height/2);

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradientRef, start, end, kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
```

And I wonder how I can make it draw into a designated view and a clipping rect passed in parameters to my function. Tip: I don't mind about drawRect, I'm not subclassing anything.

Tip 2: I don't want to insert any layers that I won't be able to remove later.

Tip 3: This piece of code does not draw anything that my eyes could see..... :-(  Missing a graphic port ?

Tip 4: I'd like to erase the draw simply changing the background color, and it's done...

Comment: You might not mind about `drawRect:` but the OS does. Do your drawing in `drawRect:`.

Comment: @Ole Begemann : What ??? Any OS in the world allows you to draw something on a designated graphic port, and Cocoa don't ? Even old MacOS allowed this... What is the problem ? Each time I want to draw a single line somewhere I have to subclass my view ? That just sounds crazy !

Comment: you can just draw to the graphics port, but you have to use openGL. You don't need a subclass though, you can use a plain old UIView and do the drawing from the view controller by calling QuartzCore functions on the layer and context associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();` will get the graphics context for the current view, so if you call this in the drawRect: method of a UIView it will draw.

I don't understand what you mean by:

> I don't mind about drawRect, I'm not
>   subclassing anything

but if you want to do custom drawing you must either override the drawRect: method or use layers. To use layers you would call `CGContextRef context =  CGLayerGetContext(theLayer);` instead of `CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`.

Ok, so I looked at the documentation and it says that you can get a CGContextRef by calling UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() from the drawRectMethod. Here's what it says: In an iOS application, you set up a UIView object to draw to and implement the drawRect: method to perform drawing. Before calling your custom drawRect: method, the view object automatically configures its drawing environment so that your code can start drawing immediately. As part of this configuration, the UIView object creates a graphics context (a CGContextRef opaque type) for the current drawing environment. You obtain this graphics context by calling the UIKit function UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext. You save and restore graphics contexts using the functions UIGraphicsPushContext and UIGraphicsPopContext.

You can create custom graphics context objects in situations where you want to draw somewhere other than your view. For example, you may want to capture a series of drawing commands and use them to create an image or a PDF file. To create the context, you use the CGBitmapContextCreate or CGPDFContextCreate function. After you have the context, you can pass it to the drawing functions needed to create your content.

When creating custom contexts, the coordinate system for those contexts is different from the native coordinate system used by iOS. Instead of the origin being in the upper-left corner of the drawing surface, it is in the lower-left corner and the axes point up and to the right. The coordinates you specify in your drawing commands must take this into consideration or the resulting image or PDF file may appear wrong when rendered. See “Creating a Bitmap Graphics Context” and “Creating a PDF Graphics Context” for details on using CGBitmapContextCreate and CGPDFContextCreate.

Comment: you can get a layer from a UIView by calling ` CGLayer *theLayer = theView.layer; `

Comment: @Rich : CGContextRef context = CGLayerGetContext((CGLayerRef*)theCell.layer);  The compiler says bad Argument type... And does not know CGLayer...

Comment: @Rich : I don't want to do custom drawing. I just want to draw a line, a rect, or here, a gradient somewhere on my view.

Comment: dont use a pointer. try this: ` CGContextRef context = CGLayerGetContext((CGLayerRef)theCell.layer); `

Comment: that's custom drawing, custom as in not what the view is already doing.

Comment: @Rich : If this is custom drawing, so what is just simple drawing ?

Comment: @Rich : Crash... Says <Error>: CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context 0x1000000

Comment: a UIView will draw it's background with a color and it will draw it's subviews, and it can do transformations. anything else is custom drawing.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry the layer property returns a CALayer.

Comment: @Rich : if you want... But I'm sorry, drawing a line somewhere on the screen had never been custom drawing. Custom drawing has always refered to draw something on a way it's not designed to be. Such as drawing a Button a different way. A view is just a port as far as I can see, so talking about custom drawing when you just to draw a line on the view is not appropriated. If you use the BgColor of the view to fill it with a gradient instead of a plain color, ok, here it's a custom drawing in the view context.

Comment: @Rich : So... There is no way on Cocoa to draw something somewhere oh the screen without subclassing everything ?

Comment: actually filling the background with a gradient isn't custom drawing. You can use a pattern ` [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:] `. And yes if you want to do any drawing using drawing functions you need to subclass UIView. It may be possible to do it in openGL, but as far as I know you need a CAEAGLLayer, which you get by subclassing UIView and overriding the layerClass method.

Comment: @Rich : Thank you, I really appreciate your help. Really. But this story sounds like a joke. I hope that people that have coded Cocoa left their job and are now selling bread at the corner of the street. I've never seen such a worse, painfull and illogic environment than iOS developping... It's just a nightmare to code just simple things. Problems on each step where you though "I will do that in 5 minutes" and days after you are still wondering why things don't work. Maybe some sleep will help... Good night. :-)

Comment: @Rich : filling the background with a gradient isn't custom drawing. You can use a pattern [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:] .  OK, 1 point for you, but that was just an example  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Might I recommend you look into the CAGradientLayer, and add it as a sublayer of your view?  Lots simpler, and it will be hardware accelerated which matters for table cells.

Example stolen partly from here:

http://tumbljack.com/post/188089679/gpu-accelerated-awesomeness-with-cagradientlayer

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>  // Also import this framework
......
CAGradientLayer grad = [CAGradientLayer layer];

UIColor *colorOne     = [UIColor colorWithHRed:1.0f Green:1.0f Blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
UIColor *colorTwo     = [UIColor colorWithHRed:0.0f Green:0.0f Blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f];

NSArray *colors =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorOne.CGColor, colorTwo.CGColor, nil];
grad.colors = colors;

CGRect rect = theCell.backgroundView.bounds; 
rect.size.height = rect.size.height / 2;
grad.frame = rect;
[self.layer addsublayer:grad]
```

You may have to play with the colors a bit, not sure if you had the gradient tilted or not...